# Appropriate Grease for Z-Axis Lead Screws

Tags: creality-ender-3, maintenance, cleaning

I need to lube the lead screw for my 3D printer. I plan on using [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BCVXUR6) grease. I want to know if this will work. There are several other ones like silicone grease, lithium grease, and synthetic grease with PTFE. I am super confused with the pros and cons of each.

Details:

- I have a metal lead screw and a metal(brass I believe) nut.
- I am using a Lotmaxx SC-10 printer(similar to Ender 3)
- I need it to repel dust.

I think it was dry, to begin with. At least I have never greased it before. If I touch it, I feel something on it, but it is super thin and I can barely feel it.

Comment: What lubricant is appropriate depends on materials involved and what previous lubricant was in use.   Some lubricants (for example, oil and graphite) may cause problems for each other. If there was no previous lubricant, this becomes an engineering design decision with many answers.

Comment: If it's just a light coating of an oil based grease, likely you could wipe it down a bit and then any of your similar semi-liquid greases would work.  Which brings you back to making the engineering decision by weighing the pros and cons of each...

Answer (score 2):

Personally I put a drop of light machine oil on the lead screw just above the Y gantry between prints, while the head is down.  When it prints, the lead screw raises the gantry and the threads spread the oil.

If I was going to do a really tall print, I'd consider adding a little oil higher up the lead screw too where it rarely goes.

A Y axis lead screw is a low speed, low pressure and low temperature application, so anything "slippery" will do, but the dust repelling attribute is important.

Sewing Machine oil, or 3-in-1 oil would be ideal, as would a white lithium grease.  You don't want a petroleum grease like in car wheel bearings because it attracts dust and is viscous/heavy, requiring more force to move around.

[image: Singer brand sewing machine oil]

Since your existing lead screw is "dry" a wipe with a clean rag should be enough to remove what was there.  I would not use degreaser or solvent, and I would also avoid anything that is in a spray can/aerosol because you want to control where it goes, and avoid overspray.

Your nominated du pont lube looks fine too, though out of stock and it seems expensive.

Comment: Should I clean the lead screw with Isopropyl Alcohol first? Many guides say to do this.

Comment: @DragonflyRobotics you could if you want,  I wouldn'tbother with anything more than a wipe.  Just let it evaporate for a couple minutes before oiling.